# Nvidia Linux graphics debugger Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: linux, qt, debugging, opengl

I have been trying to debug my OpenGL graphics application using Nvidia Linux graphics debugger, the debugger application starts and installs the debugger to the device (graphics) correctly, but when trying to Launch the application to  debug it shows this message

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the  Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".  Available platform plugins are:
>   eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, xcb. Reinstalling the
>   application may fix this problem. Aborted (core dump)

The application starts fine as standalone but starting with Linux GD.

I have seen lot of posts relating to xcb but could not find any answer relating to starting application using Nvidia linux graphics debugger

nvidia drivers I am using 378

os-ubuntu 16.04

Nvidia liniux graphics debugger 2.0

Qt opengl context

[image]

Comment: Did you try manually rebuilding the xcb plugin from `$QTDIR\5.7\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\platforms\xcb`?

Comment: Can you please provide details how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the pro file, you will see what is needed. Build will be something like: `qmake -r "LIBS+= -L/path/to/xcblib" "LIBS+=-lxcb" "INCLUDEPATH+=/path/to/xcb/include/headers" xcb.pro && make && make install`. Take alook at the mysql plugin for Qt, it has quite some results to give you a general idea

Comment: The application is working as standalone but not working from Nvidia debugger but still tried manual compiling, still not working, same error,

Comment: What worked for me was setting the `LD_PRELOAD` env variable to `~/.tgd/libs/libNvidia_gfx_debugger.so` and launching the target application. Then from the graphics debugger simply use the Attach tab.

Comment: Tried it too but no help thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by changing the **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** to the Qt installation path (on the launch environment options)

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<some_dir>/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib
```